# Displaying Date as DD-MM-YYYY within XSLT/XML

Tags: xml, date, datetime, xslt, xsd

Been trying to format the text to display as DD-MM-YYYY when pulled from XML to XSLT 1.0, since I know it has to be laid out as YYYY-MM-DD within XSD/XML when using xs:date which what I have used.

Here is the code I am working working on, Any advice on how I should display this?

**XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<events xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="events.xsd">
  <venue id="01" 
         vtitle="ExCeL Exhibition Centre" 
         location="London" 
         telephone="0844 448 7600">
   <event name="Doctor Who 50th Celebration" date="2013-10-22">
    <image>images/doctor50.jpg</image><attribute>Doctor Who Event</attribute>
    <description>A 50th Anniversary musical bonanza for Doctor Who.</description>
    <ticket_price type="adult" status="available">&#163;25.00</ticket_price>
    <ticket_price type="child" status="none">&#163;11.00</ticket_price>
    <ticket_price type="junior" status="available">&#163;0.00</ticket_price>
    <email>info@roundhouselondon.com</email>
</event>
</venue>
```

**XSD**

```
<xs:attribute name="date" type="xs:date"/>
```

**XSLT**

```
<xsl:element name="date"><xsl:value-of select="@date"/></xsl:element>
```

**HTML**

```
<date>2013-10-22</date>
```

Comment: I have to comment on this one: the [iso8601 standard for dates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) is : `YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss` (with maybe .mmm, for milliseconds, and also mention of the timezone and time shift.  (ex for the simplest form:   `2016-06-27T19:01:20.345`. Use this everywhere (log entries, filenames, etc)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Another simple solution for producing dates in dd/mm/yyyy form

```
<xsl:value-of select="
  concat(substring(@date, 9, 2), 
         '/', 
         substring(@date, 6, 2),
         '/', 
         substring(@date, 1, 4))"/>
```

Comment: I can not get this to work with your code, I have now provided my full XSLT code for you to look at above, thanks again for your help

Comment: Sorry; my sample assumes that the date is in the content of the current element, instead of in the value of an attribute.  Updated now.

Comment: Thank you very much, this helped a lot. Changed the dash inside "substring(@date, 1-4)" to a comma and the date displays correctly now

Answer (score 4):

I would use different solutions from those provided by @Stormtroopr for both 1.0 and 2.0.

In 2.0 use

```
format-date(xs:date($date), '[D01]-[M01]-[Y0001]')
```

In 1.0 use

```
concat(substring(., 9, 2), 
         '-', 
         substring(., 6, 2), 
         '-', 
         substring(., 1, 4))
```

For future reference, please tell us which version of XSLT you are using. Both 1.0 and 2.0 are in common use, and the solutions are often different.

Answer (score 1):

I am using it for SharePoint and I solved it like this

```
<xsl:value-of select=" ddwrt:FormatDate(/dsQueryResponse/Rows/Row/@Date,3,1)"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

In XSLT 2.0 you can use tokenize to split the string and then just using `xsl:for-each` and `xsl:sort` to reverse it. (I don't have an XSLT2.0 engine right now, but this is pretty close to what you'll need).

```
<xsl:for-each select="tokenize(@date,'-'">
    <xsl:sort select="position()" data-type="number" order="descending"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
</xsl:for-each>
```

**In XSLT 1.0, you do it using... recursion!**

Here is the crux of it, this takes a date, and then searches for the string before and after the first hyphen (`-`). Normally, you'd have the `substring-before` come after the processing of the `subtring-after` to preserve the order, but here we switch them to ultimately reverse the ouput.

```
<xsl:template name="reverse-date">
    <xsl:param name="text" select="."/>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="contains($text, '-')">
            <xsl:call-template name="reverse-date">
                <xsl:with-param name="text" select="substring-after($text, '-')"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
            <xsl:text>-</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($text, '-')" />
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
           <xsl:value-of select="$text"/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

Below is the complete template that will reverse the date for you based on your above XML document.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="//event"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="event">
  <xsl:element name="date">
    <!--
         ** Call this template when you want to reverse the date **
    -->
    <xsl:call-template name="reverse-date">
     <xsl:with-param name="text" select="@date" />
    </xsl:call-template>
  </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="reverse-date">
    <xsl:param name="text" select="."/>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="contains($text, '-')">
           <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($text, '-')" />
            <xsl:text>-</xsl:text>
            <xsl:call-template name="reverse-date">
                <xsl:with-param name="text" select="substring-after($text, '-')"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
           <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space($text)"/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

## In your code

You'll need to change this:

```
<xsl:element name="date"><xsl:value-of select="@date"/></xsl:element>
```

To this:

```
<xsl:element name="date">
  <xsl:call-template name="reverse-date">
    <xsl:with-param name="text" select="@date" />
  </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:element>
```

Comment: I have tried you way, and it just displays the same way YYYY-MM-DD, I have now provided my full XSLT code, for you to look at, thanks again for your help

Comment: @Sony123 Whoops, not sure what happened there. Try the code again. I've commented above the `call-template` you'll want to copy into your XSLT to get the right result.

Answer (score -1):

this piece of code probably helps:

```
    for children in child:
        if children.tag  == "dateTime":
            list_dateTime = [children.text] 
            lista=list_dateTime             
            simbolo=('/')
            simboloh=(':')            
            Lis=str(lista)
            dd=Lis[2:4]
            mm=Lis[4:6]
            yy=Lis[6:10]
            hh=Lis[10:12]
            mms=Lis[12:14]
            data=dd + simbolo + mm+  simbolo + yy+  simbolo +hh+ simboloh + mms
        if children.tag == "field":
            for subchildren in children:
                if subchildren.tag == "id":
                    list_id = [subchildren.text]
                if subchildren.tag =="value":
                    list_value = [subchildren.text]
                    arquivo.writelines('\n')
                    arquivo.writelines(list_period)
                    arquivo.writelines(',')
                    arquivo.writelines(data)
                    arquivo.writelines(',')
                    arquivo.writelines(list_id)
                    arquivo.writelines(',')
                    arquivo.writelines(list_value)
```

Comment: Why this code helps? Please explain by editing your answer