# XSLT Format Date to DD/MM/YYYY

Tags: xslt-2.0

I am very new to the technical part, hence please provide me solution for the quire in very simple steps so that i follow.

I have a XML that has a date formatted as (yy:Hire_Date) (2000-01-01-08:00).

I want this to be transformed to MM/DD/YYYY, i.e, 01/01/2000

Please help.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19759036/displaying-date-as-dd-mm-yyyy-within-xslt-xml

Just googled your title :/ seems to be the answer there !

Comment: I am not a techi guy, i am a functional guy who is working on some technical requirement, i have tried function (format-date), but not able to get the output.

Comment: Hi Toodoo, the example that you have provide is of XSLT 1.0, i need a solution in XSLT 2.0, please help.

Comment: this was simple for those who could not answer, here is the answer.. 

<xsl:value-of select="format-date(wd:Hire_Date, '[M01]/[D01]/[Y0001]')"></xsl:value-of>

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me ;);););););););););)

(xsl:value-of select="format-date(wd:Hire_Date, '[M01]/[D01]/[Y0001]')">/xsl:value-of)